# Ordered set and ordinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I have a problem with this exercise, it says:

> Given an ordered set $(S,\lt)$, an ordinal $\alpha$ embeds into $S$ if there exist an injective function $f:\alpha \rightarrow S$ such that $x \lt y \implies f(x) \lt f(y)$.
> What is the minimum cardinality of a set $S$ such that every $\alpha \lt \omega_2$ embeds into $S$?

I am pretty sure that the answer is $\aleph_1$, and maybe a useful fact is that if a non-empty set satisfies $(S,\lt) \sim (S,\lt) \times \omega_1$ (where $(S,\lt) \times \omega_1$ is ordered with the lexicographical order and $\sim$ means there is an isomorphism of orders between the tho set, $i.e.$ a non decreasing bijection) then every $\alpha \lt \omega_2$ embeds into $S$ (it can be proven by transfinite recursion).

I just need to construct an example of a set $|S|=\aleph_1$ that satisfies the request of the problem, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you solve the same problem with $\omega_2$ replaced by $\omega_1$? There the answer is different ($\aleph_0$ rather than $\aleph_1$) but the reasoning is similar and it's easier to think up an appropriate $S$.

Comment: How would $\omega_1 + 1$ embed into $\omega_1 $?

Comment: @BrianO $\omega_1+1$ cannot be embedded (order-preservingly) into $\omega_1$, but what does that have to do with the question? The question is about embeddings into linear orders (not well-orders) of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh — nothing, it has nothing to do with the question. I missed that $S$ was just a linear/total order, nowhere is either word used. Lame excuse: I was on phone.

Comment: @NoahSchweber in that case it's easier, let $\alpha$ be a countable ordinal, notice that $(\mathbb{Q}, \lt) \times \alpha$ is dense in itself and has neither maximum nor minimum, so it must be $(\mathbb{Q}, \lt) \times \alpha \sim (\mathbb{Q}, \lt)$ by Cantor's theorem. Being $f$ such an isomorphism, $g: \alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ defined as $g(\beta)=f(0,\beta)$ is an injection. So in $\mathbb{Q}$ every ordinal less than $\omega_1$ can be embedded and the answer is $\aleph_0$ as we would expect.